# Iterate an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, each, hash

I have a hash with a key of `cities` and the value is an array of hashes containing location data.  It looks like this:

```
@locations = {
    "cities"=>[
        {"longitude"=>-77.2497049, "latitude"=>38.6581722, "country"=>"United States", "city"=>"Woodbridge, VA"}, 
        {"longitude"=>-122.697236, "latitude"=>58.8050174, "country"=>"Canada", "city"=>"Fort Nelson, BC"}, 
  ... 
    ]
}
```

I'd like to iterate through and print all the values for the key `city`:

```
Woodbridge, VA
Fort Nelson, BC
...
```

Comment: Thanks for editing Sergio. I tried to indent "code" with 4 spaces but it didn't work...?

Comment: What is `@locations`?

Comment: 4-space indentation requires blank lines around the code block.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, I edited the question to define locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your corrected data format:

```
@locations = { "cities"=>[
               { "longitude"=>-77.2497049,
                 "latitude"=>38.6581722,
                 "country"=>"United States",
                 "city"=>"Woodbridge, VA"},
               { "longitude"=>-122.697236,
                 "latitude"=>58.8050174,
                 "country"=>"Canada",
                 "city"=>"Fort Nelson, BC" }] }

@locations["cities"].each { |h| puts h["city"] }
Woodbridge, VA
Fort Nelson, BC
```

or to save in an array:

```
@locations["cities"].each_with_object([]) { |h,a| a << h["city"] }
  #=> ["Woodbridge, VA", "Fort Nelson, BC"]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This did the trick. I probably would have come to this solution on my own, but I was thrown off by my original misreading of the dataset. I have updated the original question's format so that others can reference and use your answer. 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why would you have that structure, anyway, in the data format you have above, you would access it like

```
@locations[1].each { |c| p c["city"] }
```

Although, this implies that you should always expect second object in the array to be the required cities array. Further you need to put in required nil check.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried your solution and I'm getting "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass". I read that you said I new to put in a required nil check. Perhaps I haven't done that. Where about would I check for the nil?

Comment: It is possible that you don't have second element in the array. You can print `@locations` and check if it contains second element. Like `p @locations[1]`. You could alter above code to `@locations[1].each { |c| p c["city"] } unless @locations.nil? && @locations[1].nil?`. The data format you have put above looks unreliable to me.

Comment: Silly me. I think I read the data structure incorrectly. Can you please see the updated information? I put the data structure at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, you have to do the exact same thing but let me explain whats happening in there.

Your example is an array and has multiple elements which could be just string like `cities` or an array of hashes like you mentioned.

So in order to iterate through the hashes and get the city values printed, you first of all have to access the array that has hashes. By doing so

```
  @locations["cities"]
  => [{"longitude"=>-77.2497049, "latitude"=>38.6581722, "country"=>"United States", "city"=>"Woodbridge, VA"}, {"longitude"=>-122.697236, "latitude"=>58.8050174, "country"=>"Canada", "city"=>"Fort Nelson, BC"}]
```

Now that you have go the array you required, you can just integrate through them and get the result printed like this

```
 @locations["cities"].map{|hash| p hash['city']}
```

In case your getting nil errors as you have stated in comments, just see what happens when you try to access the array of hashes. if you still are experiencing issues, then you may have to provide the full input so as to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe your solution would have worked (and thanks for taking the time to explain it!), but I read the data structure incorrectly... I think. I updated the original post at the bottom. I think I'm now dealing with a hash with a key "cities", and the value is an array of hashes.

Comment: Well, then you don't have to change much, just get the key and iterate though that.